# Telemetry with APM 2.6 and XBee

Tags: quadcopter, radio-control, mavlink

The transmission of telemetry data between the ground base station and APM 2.x (Arducopter), using XBee, is not well documented. The only documentation is [Telemetry-XBee](http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/common-optional-hardware/common-telemetry-landingpage/common-telemetry-xbee/), but it does not specify what XBee version is used. I have been checking and I guess is version 1 (this one has P2P link and the others not), but I am not sure.

I would like to know, what XBee modules people use for flying drones? Do they have problems with the APM connection? How can I control the drone remotely using the XBee link with [Mavlink](http://qgroundcontrol.org/mavlink/start) protocol?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's a shopping recommendation request. Any XBee module that has the data rate and range you require should be suitable.

Comment: It is not a shopping recommendation, I am not asking for what brand to buy, I am looking for some guide, I saw there different kind of Xbee modules (serie1, serie2...). If somebody has done something similar with an arducopter examples will be appreciate.

Comment: Guidance for what? What is your problem? All you have said is that you want to transmit data. All Xbee modules transmit data. If you have actual specifications, like data rate and range, you could modify your question, but even then it would be easier for you to go to a site like Digikey and enter your specs there. Now, if you needed advice on how to calculate a required data rate or something else that would help you select the right module then that would be an appropriate question, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: @Chuck, do you fly drones? The transmission of telemetry data between the ground base station and APM 2.x (arducopter) using XBee is not well documented. I would like to know, what XBee modules people use for flying drones? do they have problems with the APM connection? is it possible to control the drone remotely using the XBee link with Mavlink protocol?

Comment: Well those aren't the questions you asked. You asked, "Somebody could give me advise about what Xbee module to buy?"

Comment: ok, I have edited the question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edit esguti, still, it is better to ask "How do I do X" rather than "Is it possible to do X". The former could be answered with "That's not possible", but the latter encourages people to answer "Yes" without explaining how. If you could add details of what you have tried so far, and what problems you had, that would help people formulate answers. If you have yet to buy, explain what research you have done (which datasheets you have read) and ask specific questions about what confuses you about what you have read.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I appreciate your suggestions, I will update the question with more info

Comment: this version is not that affordable but it worth trying:
XBee Xtend 900MHz

Comment: Hi @Mojtaba, welcome to Robotics StackExchange.  This is not much of an answer.  Can you expand and elaborate on it?